# Setting Image background for a line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set a background image to a line plot that I have done in matplotlib. While importing the image and using zorder argument also, I am getting two seperate images, in place of a single combined image. Please suggest me a way out. My code is --

```html
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import itertools

def flip(items, ncol):
    return itertools.chain(*[items[i::ncol] for i in range(ncol)])

df = pd.read_pickle('neer.pickle')
rows = list(df.index)
countries = ['USA','CHN','JPN','DEU','GBR','FRA','IND','ITA','BRA','CAN','RUS']
x = range(len(rows))
df = df.pct_change()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for country in countries:
 ax.plot(x, df[country], label=country)

plt.xticks(x, rows, size='small', rotation=75)
#legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left', shadow=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.show(1)

plt.figure(2)
im = plt.imread('world.png')
ax1 = plt.imshow(im, zorder=1)
ax1 = df.iloc[:,:].plot(zorder=2)
handles, labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(flip(handles, 2), flip(labels, 2), loc=9, ncol=12)
plt.show()
```

So in the figure(2) I am facing problem and getting two separate plots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to overlay background image over plot, we need `imshow` and `extent` parameter from `matplotlib`.

Here is an condensed version of your code. Didn't have time to clean up much.

First a sample data is created for 11 countries as listed in your code. It is then `pickled` and saved to a file (since there is no pickle file data).

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import itertools

from scipy.misc import imread



countries = ['USA','CHN','JPN','DEU','GBR','FRA','IND','ITA','BRA','CAN','RUS']

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 11), columns=list(countries))
df_sample.to_pickle('c:\\temp\\neer.pickle')
```

Next the pickle file is read and we create bar plot directly from `pandas`

```
df = pd.read_pickle('c:\\temp\\neer.pickle')
my_plot = df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,title="Plot Over Image")
my_plot.set_xlabel("countries")
my_plot.set_ylabel("some_number")
```

Next we use `imread` to read image into `plot`.

```
img = imread("c:\\temp\\world.png")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.imshow(img,zorder=0,  extent=[0.1, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0])
plt.show()
```

Here is an output plot with image as background.
As stated this is crude and can be improved further.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two separate figures in your code. The first one with `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)` and the second with `plt.figure(2)`

If you delete that second figure, you should be getting closer to your goal